# How to extract a range of rows from sequence file in Spark?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd, sequencefile

Suppose I have a very large sequence file, but I only want to work with first 1000 rows locally. How can I do that?

Currently my code looks like this

```
JavaPairRDD<IntWritable,VectorWritable> seqVectors = sc.sequenceFile(inputPath, IntWritable.class, VectorWritable.class);
```

Comment: have you tried rdd.take(1000) ?

Comment: I have it gives me an error saying it returns an array, not a RDD

Comment: Yeah, it returns you a list of 1000 elements and you can then work with it? What do you expect it to return you ?

Comment: A RDD with first 1000 elements.

Comment: Please note that "take" is an action and not transformation hence you get the List. Applying a transformation to a RDD yields in another RDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you should do is `parallelize` of these `array`:

```
JavaPairRDD<IntWritable,VectorWritable> RDDwith1000 = sc.parallelize(seqVectors.take(1000));
```

see simple example [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections) and below:

[image]